# Windows GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSession Events Not Fired in Service

Tags: windows, rust, service, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I'm trying to listen to events dispatched by [`GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.control.globalsystemmediatransportcontrolssession) in a Windows Service (in Rust).

I made a [reproduction repository](https://github.com/Nerixyz/windows-service-repro) with instructions.

The most important part is this:

```rust
session.PlaybackInfoChanged(TypedEventHandler::new(move |_, _| {
  tx.send(()).ok();
  Ok(())
}))
```

Here a new event handler is created that listens on every open application that emits SMTC metadata for changes to the playback, i.e. play/pause/stop events.

Once the event is fired, the application terminates (`rx` receives an event).

This works fine in a "regular" executable (e.g. by running `cargo run`).

However, once I'm running this as a service (through `nssm`*), no event is emitted (the log-file is not created/written to).

I couldn't find any documentation by Microsoft related to services and events. Is there a workaround, am I doing something wrong or is this known to not be supported?

(*) I'm using `nssm` here, but the same happens when I'm running the executable as a service. This however would include unnecessary code for managing the service.
So I'd guess the problem is that the executable doesn't run with the user-account.
Then I'm wondering why I can get the sessions, and even metadata, in the first place and no error is thrown/emitted.

Comment: I guess audio/sounds are in the "interactive" category. Interactive Services are very special https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services and more special (ie: limited) since Windows Vista: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/larryosterman/interacting-with-services

Comment: Thanks for the links! I was a bit confused becuase I can get the metadata like title and artist but can't get any events (but I can listen to them).

Comment: Do you develop UWP app?

Comment: No, I'm not developing a UWP app.